# bundles in java?

Tags: java, php, python, django, symfony1

in symfony 2.0 and django there are bundles that contain everything for a feature (html, css, js, img, php/python).

so if you want to delete one feature, you basically just delete that bundle and unregister it from "main".

are there java frameworks for this too? or is it different in java cause java is a compiling language.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, libraries and programs are normally packaged in [JAR files](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/). Java does not have its own package management system to install or remove features. Web applications are packaged in [WAR files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28Sun_file_format%29), which are just JAR files with a specific layout.

This has nothing to do with Java being a compiled language.

Answer (score 1):

Are osgi-bundles what you search ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the closest thing in Javaland is the venerable Web Application Archive (war file).